# Using Style Manager in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, markers, font, style-manager

On my desktop PC, I am using Ministry of Transportation Ontario road shields to label major highways on my maps.  I often need to work with a laptop when I'm visiting a client at their location, so I copied the appropriate style files to the same folder on my laptop.  When I try to apply the roads shield markers on the laptop, it gives me weird symbols and text instead of the appropriate shield.  I had no problem doing this on my desktop, so I must be missing something.

On the left (in the image below), I have an example of the road shield marker style that displays on maps on my PC.  On the right (column highlighted in yellow) are the marker symbol options I get in the style manager menu when I try to access these shields when using the laptop.  I assume this is a simple fix and I'm overlooking something.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be that the symbol depends on certain files that are unavailable on your laptop...

- Check if it uses a particular font.
- Check that linked

Comment: I'll give this one to you Matthew.  I had overlooked the step that involved adding the appropriate font files.  I had only added the sheilds in the appropriate ArcGIS folder.  Thanks